# Compare two string apparently they are equal

Tags: php

I'm trying to compare 2 string. I get the first string get from an array, the second I get to read a directory. The problem is that I am trying to compare the array name matches that of the file that reading and are identical. the string is:

```
algo está cambiando.mp3
```

It is present in the array and directory.

I put to print the following messages to check:

array length:30   algo está cambiando.mp3 // array element

file length:23    algo está cambiando.mp3 // file

I'm doing with this code to compare and always throws me is false. I do not know because they are different.

```
echo  "<br>array length:  ".mb_strlen(($arrayPosiciones[$x])). " ".  ($arrayPosiciones[$x]);
echo  "<br>file length:".mb_strlen(($d)). "  ".($d)  ;
```

I think that is the problem of accents or something. I have tried in many ways. Even the array I put the htmlentities for items that have a tilde. with htmlentities the word displays correctly.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($arrayPosiciones); $i++){
  $arrayPosiciones[$i]=htmlentities($arrayPosiciones[$i]);
}
```

What I can do? I'm iterating a directory and compare the current file is equal to this in the $arrayPosiciones.

```
$ruta=$_REQUEST['ruta'];
$dir =scandir($ruta);
foreach($dir as $d){
 if(substr($d,-3)=='Mp3' || substr($d,-3)=='mp3' || substr($d,-3)=='MP3' ||  substr($d,-3)=='WMA' || substr($d,-3)=
   for( $x=0; $x<count($arrayPosiciones); $x++){
    if($arrayPosiciones[$x]==$d){ echo "is the same!"; }
    .
    .
    .


echo "<br>array: ". strlen(trim($arrayPosiciones[$x]));
echo "<br>file: ". strlen(trim($d));
if( strlen(trim($arrayPosiciones[$x])) ==strlen(trim($d)) ){
   echo "===";
}

array: 30
file: 23
```

Comment: It could be character encoding -- `strlen()` returns *bytes*, not characters; [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) would probably be a better choice here. However, 7 bytes difference is a *lot* for a simple "á". Are you sure there aren't just some spaces on the end that you're not seeing? What does `strlen(trim($arrayPosiciones[$x]))` show you? Where are your strings coming from? Do you have influence over their character encodings?

Comment: @MattGibson I corrected but still have the problem. Thank you

Comment: @MattGibson echo "<br>array: ". strlen(trim($arrayPosiciones[$x]));
echo "<br>file: ". strlen(trim($d));
if( strlen(trim($arrayPosiciones[$x])) ==strlen(trim($d)) ){
 echo "===";
}

Comment: @MattGibson   array: 30
    file: 23

Comment: Okay, so let's find out what's *really* in these strings. `echo bin2hex($d);` and the same for the array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this snippet and works on a linux server, but not in mac.

```
<?php   
// In the very first line of your code
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');


foreach($dir as $d){
 if(substr($d,-3)=='Mp3' || substr($d,-3)=='mp3' || substr($d,-3)=='MP3'){
     $encoded_d = htmlentities($d, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
     $encoded_a = htmlentities($arrayPosiciones[0], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
     if($encoded_d == $encoded_a){ 
          echo "is the same!"; 
       }else{
           echo "nope"; 
       }
    }
}
```

on a Windows server:

```
$ruta= getcwd();//$_REQUEST['ruta'];
$dir =scandir($ruta);
$arrayPosiciones[0] = "algo está cambiando";
foreach($dir as $d){
 if(substr($d,-3)=='Mp3' || substr($d,-3)=='mp3' || substr($d,-3)=='MP3'){
     $encoded_a = htmlentities($d, ENT_COMPAT, 'iso-8859-1'); 
     $encoded_d = mb_convert_encoding($arrayPosiciones[1], 'iso-8859-1');

    echo ($encoded_d);echo "<br>";
    echo ($encoded_a);echo "<br>";

    if($encoded_d == $encoded_a){ 
        echo "is the same!"; 
    }else{
        echo "nope"; 
    }
}
}
```

In my windows server works correctly if I set the the parameter url-encode `iso-8859-1` and keep `UTF-8` for the file in array.

Comment: thanks for answering. but for testing your files you tested with accents?.

Comment: Yes i tested with this  file name "algo está cambiando.mp3"

Comment: Works on your server?

Comment: I'm trying. I have my files locally. what I do is read a directory, store the data in an array. and then compare them with the directory.

Comment: Are you using windows or linux server?

Comment: I tried your linux code did not work. I tried your code windows. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108673/discussion-between-yavg-and-cesare).

Comment: can depends from default charset of php environments. what print if you do encode for each string? what print if you don't manipulate text?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is caused by different encodings while storing in the file and while in the array. Use mb_convert_encoding to convert them to one encoding and then compare.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php